Morse index of geodesics with variable initial velocities
Given a unit-speed geodesic $\gamma : [0, \ell] \rightarrow M$, one defines the index form $I(X, Y)$ for vector fields $X, Y$ along $\gamma$. The index of the geodesic $\textrm{Ind}(\gamma)$ is then defined as the maximum dimension of a subspace of vector fields along $\gamma$, on which $I$ is negative definite. The Morse index theorem gives precise desciription of $\textrm{Ind}(\gamma|_{[0,T]})$ as $0 \le T \le \ell$ varies.
Now, let us assume that $M$ is complete. Then, for each unit vector $\mathbf{v} \in S(TM)$, we have a unique unit-speed geodesic $\gamma_{\mathbf{v}} : [0, \ell] \rightarrow M$, with $\dot\gamma_{\mathbf{v}}(0) = \mathbf{v}$. We then have a function
$$\begin{aligned} I = I(\ell) : S(TM) &\rightarrow \mathbb{N} \\\\ \mathbf{v} &\mapsto \mathrm{Ind}(\gamma_{\mathbf{v}}).\end{aligned}$$
What can we say about this $I$? Is this semi-continuous or locally constant? My very naive intuition is the following. Since $I(\gamma)$ is the sum of dimension of kernels of the exponential map (i.e., multiplicities of the focal points), and since rank is lower semi-continuous, the map $I$ should be upper semi-continuous. That is, for any fixed $\mathbf{v}_0 \in S(TM)$, we should have $I(\mathbf{v}) \le I(\mathbf{v}_0)$ in a neighborhood of $\mathbf{v}_0$. But I am unable to justify this.
Any comment or reference will be highly appreciated. Cheers!
UPDATE: Upon some more thought, I have a possible direction. For $\mathbf{v}_0 \in S(TM)$ fixed, consider a contractible neighborhood $\mathbf{v}_0 \in U \subset S(TM)$. Consider the family of geodesics $\Lambda : U \times [0, \ell] \rightarrow M$ given by $\Lambda(\mathbf{v}, t) = \exp(t \mathbf{v}) = \gamma_{\mathbf{v}}$. One can think of $\Lambda$ as an $(n-1)$-dimensional geodesic variation of $\gamma_{\mathbf{v}_0}$. Now, for any vector field $X$ along $\gamma_{\mathbf{v}_0}$, we can get an extension, say, $\tilde{X}$ along $\Lambda$. In particular, for each $\mathbf{v} \in U$, we have a vector field $\tilde{X}(\mathbf{v})$ along $\gamma_{\mathbf{v}}$, so that $\tilde{X}(\mathbf{v}_0) = X$. Now, suppose $I(\gamma_{\mathbf{v}_0}) = k$, and choose a basis of vector fields $X_1, \cdots, X_k$ so that $I(X_i, X_i) < 0$ for all $1 \le i \le k$. Then, from the continuity of the index form, we get for $\mathbf{v} \in U$ sufficiently close to $\mathbf{v}_0$, we have $I(\tilde{X}_i(\mathbf{v}), \tilde{X}_i(\mathbf{v})) < 0$ as well. This shows that $I(\gamma_{\mathbf{v}}) \ge k = I(\gamma_{\mathbf{v}_0})$.
With my earlier intuition, it then seems that $I$ is locally constant.Is my reasoning correct?
